# SQL Server: Search input on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

i was trying to search a single term on multiple columns. i got error because one of column was date time. how could i make a generic search with in-line sql. this way i tried.

```
create table tbl_test1
(id int identity(1,1),
column1 nvarchar(50),
coulmn2 nvarchar(50),
coulmn3 nvarchar(50),
coulmn4 datetime)-- Create a table 

insert into tbl_Test1 (column1,coulmn2,coulmn3,coulmn4) values
('Griff','Serjey','Maciej',GETDATE()),
('King','Fisher','Ajay',GETDATE()),
('Paul','Griff','Serjey',GETDATE()),
('King','Fisher','Griff',GETDATE())

select * from tbl_Test1 where 'Griff' IN (column1,coulmn2,coulmn3,coulmn4)
```

i got this error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Comment: coulmn4 is datetime. Datetime is incompatible with string. You use it in IN clause.

Comment: @PawełDyl yes i know but looking for best idea. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 2012,,you can use..TRY_Convert

```
select * from #tbl_Test1 
where 'Griff'
 IN (column1,coulmn2,coulmn3,try_convert(varchar(10),coulmn4))
```

You may need to do similar cast and convert on other columns when you search with date columns

Comment: getting error when execute your code the error is `'varchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Comment: if i use convert instead of try_convert then all goes fine but try_convert throwing error `'varchar' is not a recognized built-in function name.` i am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: may be you are using try_convert like this..try_convert (columnname,varchar)

Answer (score 1):

to fix your requirement, you can first convert `column4`, your`datetime` column to `nvarchar(max)` first

```
select * from tbl_Test1 where 'Griff' IN
 (column1,coulmn2,coulmn3,convert(nvarchar(max),coulmn4))
```

however this is not recommended to do so because of performance issues `=x`

Answer (score 0):

You already know that your column4 is of type datetime then why do we search your string with that column. Just ignore that column

Try like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_test1
WHERE 'Griff' IN (
        column1
        ,coulmn2
        ,coulmn3
        )
```